# Does an AZDO pipeline template have access to build variables?

Tags: azure-devops

Consider this in a pipeline template:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Create NuGet packages (dotnet pack)'
  condition: ${{ parameters.deployPackages }}
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: >-
      pack ${{ parameters.workingPath }}/${{ parameters.solution }} 
      -c ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }} 
      --no-restore 
      --include-source 
      -o $(Build.ArtifactsStagingDirectory)
      /p:PackageVersion=${{ parameters.packVersion }}
```

When I look at the pipeline failure, the `Build.ArtifactsStagingDirectory` is not expanded for any of the following variations:

```
$(Build.ArtifactsStagingDirectory)
$BUILD_ARTIFACTSSTAGINGDIRECTORY
${{ Build.ArtifactsStagingDirectory }}
```

I wonder if this is specific to the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task and the way it passed the custom argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you should be using is `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. That said, if the variable doesn't exist, using that syntax, it should expand to the reference itself (as opposed to a null or empty value.

Also, try confirming your result outside the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task with something like:

```
- pwsh: Write-Host "Staging Directory is $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
  displayName: Check Staging Directory
```

Comment: Hi @danny-v, If this answer is helpful, would you please accept it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Also of note, the documentation says the Build variables are not available in templates, which is false. At least for this specific variable.

Comment: The build variables are available to you *based on syntax*. `${{ variables.variableName }}` will not work in a template unless the variable is declared in that template file, or is a system variable not dependent on runtime conditions. `$(variableName)` does work in a template, because it is expanded at runtime.